# Supports for dense Voronoi pieces

Tags: slicing, support-structures

I have printed 1 voronoi piece before. I was able to get the supports that were inside the structure out with tweezers because the holes were big enough. This one (pic below) I do not think I can do that with. I looked at the proposed support structure preview in my slicer (I use Cura) and it wants to print them inside the torso here as well. Is there a way to force the slicer to not print supports within a hollow piece? I use cura but I can use another slicer if need be. Or any other recommendations for a successful print here would be fine as well.

[image]

Comment: In general, Voronoi objects shouldn't need any support at all.  Have you tried printing without support to see how it turns out?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - that may be true on a resin printer, but on an FDM printer, voronoi objects have some pretty severe overhangs in places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One feature of Cura is the ability to set supports to build plate only. This would remove any supports internal to the model, as your model has a base that is not considered the build plate or raft. In the image provided, you would have some complications, I believe, as there would be no supports on the outside of the model if it was directly over the base.

[image: cura support settings]

As you are not eliminating other options, you can also turn off supports in Cura, load your model into Meshmixer and make use of their support feature, which allows you to adjust placement, size and other parameters in order to get a good result.

The flexibility is limited only by your imagination:

[image: meshmixer supports]